# React native in app purchase not giving latest receipt

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase

I am using react-native-iap package. I am trying to get latest subscription and check its validity

```
    await RNIap.validateReceiptIos(receiptBody, true).then((receipt) => {
    try {
        const renewalHistory = receipt.latest_receipt_info
        const expiration = renewalHistory[0].expires_date_ms
        expired = Date.now() > expiration
        productId = renewalHistory[0].product_id
    } catch (error) {}
})
```

I am multiple auto renewal subscription in a single group. I subscribe to one and I execute code above give me the subscribed product and i tag it as subscribed. First try works fine. Now after that I subscribe again another package and run code above gives me the previous subscription not the current that i subscribed. Sometime second steps also works fine but issue came in third step. Reason I found is I am not getting latest subscribed receipt info in `latest_receipt_info` above.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this tutoriel on YouTube it may help you : https://youtu.be/4JLHRV2kiCU

Also, here is what he said in the comment section :
where I write renewalHistory[renewalHistory.length - 1], this works fine in the test environment. HOWEVER, it seems that when the app is published, this doesn't work and you should instead do renewalHistory[0].
I fixed this in my app by first trying to validate using the production URL, using renewalHistory[0].
If you receive a 21007 status code after trying to validate with the production URL, you validate using the test URL using renewalHistory[renewalHistory.length - 1]